# How to update device category for device in intune?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api, intune, microsoft-graph-intune

More specifically, What I am trying to do is to loop through all intunemanageddevices and updated the device category based off of matching the serial number that is listed in a csv file. Example: If the script finds any serial number that is in both the csv and intune, to update the device category to 'in use'. I already I have this category created and the devicecategory id.

How can I modify this script? So far, I have something like this but I dont know how to add the foreach loop with the foreach like I have below:

```bash
Connect-MSGraph

Update-MSGraphEnvironment -SchemaVersion 'beta'

function Set-DeviceCategory {

  param(

    [Parameter(Mandatory)]

    [string]$DeviceID,


    [Parameter(Mandatory)]

    [string]$DeviceCategory

  )

  $body = @{ '@odata.id' = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/deviceCategories/$DeviceCategory" }

  Invoke-MSGraphRequest -HttpMethod PUT -Url "deviceManagement/managedDevices/$DeviceID/deviceCategory/`$ref"
  -Content $body

}

$devices = (Invoke-MSGraphRequest -HttpMethod GET -Url 'deviceManagement/managedDevices').value

$devices | ForEach-Object {

  if ($_.serialnumber -eq 'serial') {

    $deviceCategory = 'category id'

    Write-Host "Set device category '$deviceCategory' for $($_.serialnumber)"

    Set-DeviceCategory -DeviceID $_.id -DeviceCategory $deviceCategory

  }
  else {

    'Failed to update'

  }

}
```

I tried nesting the foreach loops but doesnt seem to work. No error either.

Comment: Thanks; I've tweaked the formatting with indentation that helps readability, and I've added another tag that hopefully attracts subject-matter experts (Personally, I can't be of further help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
Connect-MSGraph
Update-MSGraphEnvironment -SchemaVersion 'beta'
function Set-DeviceCategory 
{
    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$DeviceID,
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [string]$DeviceCategory

    )
    Write-Host "Setting device category: $DeviceCategory, for device: $DeviceID"
    $body = @{ '@odata.id' = "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/deviceCategories/$DeviceCategory" }
    Invoke-MSGraphRequest -HttpMethod PUT -Url "deviceManagement/managedDevices/$DeviceID/deviceCategory/`$ref" -Content $body

}

$intuneDevices = (Invoke-MSGraphRequest -HttpMethod GET -Url 'deviceManagement/managedDevices').value
$referenceDevices = Import-Csv 'PATH TO CSV HERE' #Assuming we have columns for DeviceName, and DeviceSerial
$deviceCategory = 'category id' 

foreach ($Device in $intuneDevices)
{
    if ($referenceDevices.DeviceSerial -contains $Device.serialnumber) 
    {
        Set-DeviceCategory -DeviceID $Device.id -DeviceCategory $deviceCategory
    }
    else 
    {
        #Maybe set it to a different category if its not in your list?
    }
}
```

You could also probably speed up the time taken to get all the intune devices if you use a filter. Also if you have more than 1k devices, you will need to use a foreach and get each 1k page of results, as Graph calls are paginated:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/paging

Comment: Thank you very much! Works well! By the way, since graph calls are paginated would the -all switch be all what’s needed? If I was to make another foreach loop, how would that be? Within the if statement of set-device category?

Comment: If you used something like: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.devicemanagement/get-mgdevicemanagementmanageddevice?view=graph-powershell-1.0
rather than the invoke command, yeah looks like you can use the all switch. You can nest multiple foreach within foreach, you would just give the item a different name, in the example above I have used $Device as the name of each item in the foreach, so the nested foreach could be anything else, and you can still use the $Device within the nested foreach.

Comment: Thats true. Or I could do a do until loop until it stops asking for a next link.but I would need to creat an authorization header connector for that. But for now, I simply added the next link pages url as a variable and added it to my for each. Thank you again for your help!

Comment: By the way, do you know how you would filter out devices in other states? Example, the csv includes a column called “state” and some devices show as “in use” and some show as “retired”. I am wondering how I can update the categories to in use but not update the ones that show as retired.

Comment: You could just add to the existing IF statement like this:
`if (($referenceDevices.DeviceSerial -contains $Device.serialnumber) -and ($Device.State -eq 'in use'))`

Comment: This didn’t work for me. State is the column name in the csv for the device category name. Wouldn’t it be referencedevices.state -eq “in use”? I tried that and still no luck. The only luck I have is doing device.devucecategorydisplayname -eq “in use” and the same in my else if statement except with -eq “retired” and to update to retired category. This does it but it doesn’t work if the device is in use.

Comment: ah wups sorry yeah it would be referenceDevices but your not in a foreach for that, so it would need more tweaking: 
`foreach ($Device in $intuneDevices)
{
    $matchingReference = $referenceDevices | Where-Object DeviceSerial -eq $Device.serialnumber
    if ($matchingReference -and ($matchingReference.State -eq 'in use')) 
    {
        Set-DeviceCategory -DeviceID $Device.id -DeviceCategory $deviceCategory
    }
    else 
    {
        #Action for if there is no matching device in the csv or state isnt in use
    }
}`

Comment: Ahhhh i see!!! And for my other 5 categories I can just add a else if condition for each state. Awesome. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Another question for you lol. In the scenario I have you before about the two categories “in use” and “retired”, let’s say I have a third category in Intune called “unassigned”. How can I add a elseif statement to only change the category of all objects in the csv that has the “retired” category only if the existing category in intune is in the “unassigned” category? Would it be something like elseif ($matchingreference.state -eq “retired” | where - object device.devicecategorydisplayname -eq “unassigned”) ?

Comment: Or would I have to add it to the for each instead like: foreach ($Device in $intuneDevices) {     $matchingReference = $referenceDevices | Where-Object DeviceSerial -eq $Device.serialnumber  -and device.devicecategorydisplayname -eq “unassigned” ?

Comment: I figured it out. I just had to add it to the if statement. Like  if ($matchingReference -and ($matchingReference.State -eq 'in use') -and ($Device.devicecategorydisplayname -contains ‘unknown’). Unknown is the unassigned category in graph.